# Get the percentage of predicted values

Tags: python, pandas

Using basic logistic regression i predicted 0 and 2 values

The DATA dataframe has the next structure:

```
Duration | y 
 12.45   | 0
 123.66  | 0
 0.34    | 2
 14.69   | 2
```

The logistic regression:

```
x = DATA.Duration.values.reshape(-1,1)
y = DATA.y.values.reshape(-1,1)

lgr = LogisticRegression(max_iter = 200)
lgr.fit(x,y)
lgr.score(x,y)
X = np.arange(0,200,10).reshape(-1,1)
Y = lgr.predict(X)
```

If to plot the result I get the picture like this:
[image]

My goal is to count amount of red and blue dots separatedly "covered" by line (predicted).

I used the next approach:

```
(np.count_nonzero(Y == 0)*100)/np.count_nonzero(y == 0)  
(np.count_nonzero(Y == 2)*100)/np.count_nonzero(y == 2)
```

But it gives strange results. What is the raight way to obtain the desired percentage?

Answer (score 1):

Using sklearn:
it is

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X)
```